# Using cleartext connections with android P

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

According to the docs it seems no more possible to use HTTP connections but only HTTPS is allowed. However it's not clear what it means:

1. What happens if I open a raw socket? Is it still applicable?
2. Does it mean the user can't navigate anymore using HTTP? The network configuration option seems it allows only fixed domain but my app can access to any domain according to the user selection

Comment: "The network configuration option seems it allows only fixed domain" -- no, use `<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">` to have it affect everything by default. Then again, the whole change seems to have not yet happened. See [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74474821) and [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74444164). You can experiment with how your app behaves by using `<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">` on Android 7.0+.

Comment: So you are saying that I just need to set that flag to true. Thanks. As you said the enforcement is not active now so I can't test it to verify the configuration but thanks again

Comment: "So you are saying that I just need to set that flag to true" -- well, ideally, you use only encrypted connections. `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"` is a fallback measure. Again, ideally, you would only apply that on a per-domain basis. Perhaps that's not possible in your app.

Comment: no, not possible I don't know the domains selected by the user